# Ubuntu Boots Into Desktop Background

Tags: 14.04, unity

When I boot Ubuntu it loads and shows only the desktop background. I have a black cross cursor and can right click to show the expected context menu for the desktop.

I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>  to get a terminal<kbd>F1</kbd>to<kbd>F6</kbd> (`tty1` to `tty6`) from which I have tried a lot of things suggested to others with similar issues on here.

I tried the basic `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` which didn't help. I tried restarting lightdm. Updated nvidia drivers. Nothing made a difference.

One post said the issue was to do with the ccsm unity plugin being disabled. I managed to get that program to run and the plugin was disabled but enabling it has made no difference.

One suggested that unity needed reinstalling so I ran `sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity`. It reinstalled but didn't fix the problem.

Another said to install `GNOME` then switch back to unity which didn't work (though I could load gnome without any problems). I also ran a few commands which were supposed to set the defaults and reset settings though I can't remember what they were exactly. As you may have guessed those had no effect too.

Anyone have any ideas? I would just reinstall Ubuntu from usb but I have no way to get it onto a USB to do so.

Edit: The linked duplicate answer is one I had already tried and found didn't solve my issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem using MATE 1.8 under Ubuntu 14.04 and after hours i ended up installing Cinnamon (which i'm more than happy now with, btw.), to get a working desktop to find out what's going wrong.

The solution was to disable all the autostart programs from MATE inside my user profile.
I've moved all .desktop files out of ~/.config/autostart/ and then been able to login to MATE again.

I'm 99% sure your problem will be fixed by disabling your autostart items.

Comment: Deleting the compiz.desktop file seems to have worked. :D Just gotta redo all my settings I assume.

Answer (score 1):

For the Desktop Issue use these commands,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop unity -y
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-desktop unity -y
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop -y
sudo apt-get upgrade -y 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
sudo apt-get autoclean -y
sudo reboot
```

As for your USB, go on someone else's computer, Install UNetBootIN and Burn the ISO

Comment: That hasn't worked for me. :/

Comment: Install Cinnamon then.....

Comment: He didn't need to install Cinnamon. Just deleted .compiz.desktop file in ~/config/autostart folder.
From my comment, you may have thinked that my solution was to install another Window Manager. This was only to be able to have a desktop which made it easier to apply the fix. I'm using XFCE and Compiz meanwhile, btw. :-)